# R and C++ iteration

Tags: c++, r, loops, rcpp

I'm trying to write a function that runs a loop in C++ from R using Rcpp.

I have a matrix Z which is one row shorter than the matrix OUT that the function is supposed to return because each position of first row of OUT will be given by the scalar sigma_0.

The function is supposed to implement a differential equation. Each iteration depends on a value from the matrix Z as well as a previously generated value of the matrix OUT.

What I've got is this:

```
cppFunction('
    NumericMatrix sim(NumericMatrix Z, long double sigma_0, long double delta, long double omega, long double gamma) {
        int nrow = Z.nrow() + 1, ncol = Z.ncol();
        NumericMatrix out(nrow, ncol);

        for(int q = 0; q < ncol; q++) {
            out(0, q) = sigma_0;
        }



        for(int i = 0; i < ncol; i++) {

            for(int j = 1; j < nrow; j++) {
                long double z = Z(j - 1, i);
                long double sigma = out(j - 1, i);
                out(j, i) = pow(abs(z * sigma) - gamma * z * sigma, delta);

            }
        }


        return out;
    }
')
```

Unfortunately I'm fairly certain it doesn't work. The function runs but the values calculated are incorrect - I've checked with simple examples in Excel and plain R-coding. I've stripped the main differentialequation apart trying to build it up step by step to see when the implementation i Excel and R using C++ starts to differ. Which seems to be when I start using the abs() function and power() function but I simply can't narrow the problem down. Any help would be greatly appreciated - also I might mention this is the first time for me using C++ and C++ along with R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `fabs` rather than `abs`. `abs` operates on `int`s, while `fabs` operates on doubles / floats.

Comment: Yep that does the trick. Thank You so much....just spend half a day on that so its greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 -- One of those things that are painful because both are defined in C...  It would be nice if you (@user2055639) could now 'upvote' and 'accept' the answer as is common on StackOverflow.

Comment: I would love to @DirkEddelbuettel. Just did the accept did not have enough reputation for up vote.